# Student Visa for France for 64 year old

Tags: france

I'm 64 and semi-retired.  I received my masters degree in 2013 and wish to study in France to broaden my professional expertise for consulting purposes.

Comment: Questions about long term migration, including student visas, belong on [expatriates.se]. That said, there isn't actually a question here.

Comment: Are you asking whether French student visas are restricted by age?  Something else?